# The 'this' prepended in function parameter with C#

Tags: c#, this

The [Real World Functional Programming](http://www.manning.com/petricek/) has this code in page 65.

The Tuple has two properties Item1 and Item2, and it has TupleExtensions class as follows.

```
static class TupleExtensions {
  public static Tuple<T1, T2> WithItems2<T1, T2> 
    (this Tuple<T1, T2> tuple, T2 newItem2) { // line3 ???
      return Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, newItme2); //  line4 ???
  }
}

var pragueOld = Tuple.Create("Prague", 1188000);
var pragueNew = pragueOld.WithItem2(pragueOld.Item2 + 13195);
```

The `pragueOld.WithItem2()` has only one parameter, but the definition has two parameters.

I think line 3, 4 is the same as this code.

```
(T2 newItem2) {
return Tuple.Create(this.Item1, newItem2)
```

What's the meaning of `this` as is prepended in the first parameter? What advantages does `this` provides compared to the simple `this.Item1` usage?

Comment: Please read about extension methods.  It's like right there in the basic part of the definition of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the this keyword, in this context, means that you are declaring an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

To declare an extension method you must be in the scope of a static class and the method must also be marked static.

This would be an example

```
namespace Utils
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static int NonWhitespaceLength(this string text)
        {
            return text.Replace(" ","").Length;
        }
    }
}
```

and you could call this by either

```
var a = "hello world ! !    !";

Console.WriteLine(Utils.StringExtension.NonWhitespaceLength(a));
```

or simply

```
using Utils.StringExtension;

var a = "hello world ! !    !";

Console.WriteLine(a.NonWhitespaceLength());
```

an additional note: the "this" parameter can actually be null. Which isn't that intuitive and it took me a while to realize, so you can either expect the function to fail if null is passed, or add null reference checks, like so:

```
namespace Utils
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static int NonWhitespaceLength(this string text)
        {
            return text == null ? 0 : text.Replace(" ","").Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From memory, that method is there so you can avoid explicitly specifying the types in the Tuple constructor, because I don't think the same generic type inference rules apply to constructors as do to methods. **Edit:** Yeah I tested it, you would have to write `new Tuple<string, int>("Prague", 5)` instead of `Tuple.Create("Prague", 5)`

Comment: Ah I see, it makes a little more sense to me now.

Comment: you can be sure it's not useless because Jon Skeet had a hand in it :-P But yeah, you should edit that part out of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case method WithItem2 is an extension method. It was added to c# to allow developers add "virtual" methods to existing classes without modifing source code. "this" keyword tells that new method belongs to Tuple type in your case 
[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very contrived example.

The `this` in the argument is the way C# implements an extension (sometimes called a mixin).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Extensions allow you to add methods for a class that you cannot change; i.e. don't have source code for.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

> Extension methods are defined as
>   static methods but are called by using
>   instance method syntax. Their first
>   parameter specifies which type the
>   method operates on, and the parameter
>   is preceded by the this modifier.
>   Extension methods are only in scope
>   when you explicitly import the
>   namespace into your source code with a
>   using directive.

The example given is

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

where the usage would be s.WordCount().  In your Tuple example, the method arguments are (this Tuple tuple, T2 newItem2) so the usage is expectedly t.WithItem2(newItem2).